# Jquery val function join array inside existing values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a imageUploader.
If my idinput has a value i want to keep the values which ones are already existing and join the new values inside the val function.

See my if else statement. The If is working fine just need the else.

See my code :

```
            if(imgIdInput.val('')) {
                imgIdInput.val(attachmentids);
            } else {
                // imgIdInput.val(attachmentids) + new values which are saved as well in attachmentids... so the old one + the new values. 
            }
```

hopefully someone has a solution :D

Comment: What do you mean "join" the values? Should they be concatenated?

Comment: exactly so i can get it twice attachmentids.attachmentids.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand, what exactly you need without related html.

First of all, if you need to check, if current value is empty, you are doing it wrong. `if (imgIdInput.val(''))` will set value to empty string. To check, if it is empty use `if (imgIdInput.val() == "")`.

To add new values to the ones you already have use `imgIdInput.val(imgIdInput.val() + ", " + newValues)`. I used comma as separator just to show how it works.

If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify your question.